# html/php comment box not sending an email

Tags: php, forms, email

I have a simple html form that sends a request to a php file which in turn should send an email. The request to the php file works and the confirmation text is displayed but no email is sent.

I'm really stuck and can't work out why the email is not being sent. Is their any problems with my php?

**HTML**

```
<form name="htmlform" method="post" action="html_form_send.php">
    <table width="450px">
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <td valign="top">
         <label for="first_name">First Name *</label>
     </td>
     <td valign="top">
       <input  type="text" name="first_name" maxlength="50" size="30">
     </td>
        </tr>

       <tr>
       <td valign="top">
           <label for="last_name">Last Name *</label>
       </td>
       <td valign="top">
          <input  type="text" name="last_name" maxlength="50" size="30">
       </td>
       </tr>
        <tr>
        <td valign="top">
             <label for="email">Email Address *</label>
        </td>
        <td valign="top">
              <input  type="text" name="email" maxlength="80" size="30">
        </td>

         </tr>
         <tr>
         <td valign="top">
             <label for="telephone">Estimated Quantity</label>
         </td>
          <td valign="top">
                <input  type="text" name="telephone" maxlength="30" size="30">
          </td>
          </tr>
         <tr>
          <td valign="top">
                <label for="comments">Product wanted for import *</label>
          </td>
          <td valign="top">
               <textarea  name="comments" maxlength="1000" cols="25" rows="6">  
           </textarea>
          </td>

          </tr>
           <tr>
           <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center">
               <input type="submit" value="Submit"> 
           </td>
           </tr>
    </table>
 </form>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

    $email_to = "jplustradingltd@gmail.com";

    $email_subject = "J Plus Trading Website Query";


    function died($error) {
        // your error code can go here
        echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
        echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
        echo $error."<br /><br />";
        echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
        die();
    }

    // validation expected data exists
    if(!isset($_POST['first_name']) ||
        !isset($_POST['last_name']) ||
        !isset($_POST['email']) ||
        !isset($_POST['telephone']) ||
        !isset($_POST['comments'])) {
        died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');       
    }

    $first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // required
    $last_name = $_POST['last_name']; // required
    $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
    $telephone = $_POST['telephone']; // not required
    $comments = $_POST['comments']; // required

    $error_message = "";
    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
  if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
    $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$last_name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Last Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
  if(strlen($comments) < 2) {
    $error_message .= 'The Comments you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
  if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
    died($error_message);
  }
    $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";

    function clean_string($string) {
      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
    }

    $email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Last Name: ".clean_string($last_name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Telephone: ".clean_string($telephone)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Comments: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";


// create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  
?>

<!-- place your own success html below -->

Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon.

<?php
}
die();
?>
```

Comment: What is the error? Is your server is configure to send mails?

Comment: Is this hosted on a set of shared servers somewhere? Or do you own the hosting?

Comment: Change `@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);` to `error_reporting(E_ALL);mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);` and see the error.

Comment: It is on a shared server. I'm using a small orange hosting, I will check to see how to enable sending of emails.

Comment: Narek. I have done what you said, but how do I see the error log?

Answer (score 0):

Download the plugin for the upload form from here  : http://phpfileuploader.com/